# Where Do I input my code(Pyside2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

Hello there I have made a ui file in qt designer that I converted into a py file but I was wondering where I can input my functions for buttons in this program

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

file = QFile("mainwindow.ui")
file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)

loader = QUiLoader()
window = loader.load(file)
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>599</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>231</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Arial Black</family>
      <pointsize>18</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Press this button</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>60</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>91</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Arial Black</family>
      <pointsize>16</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Press</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

So can you please indicate where I can start writing functions for buttons and so on,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which buttons?, shows your .ui

Comment: What do you mean all I want to know is where to put my code for button functions

Comment: I need to know how you have defined the buttons, so I ask you to show the contents of the .ui, can you do it?

Comment: ok I will post the converted python file that has buttons

Comment: just publish the .ui, it's an .xml file, why can not it? :)

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/ljjwljvwlcfr1i5/someting.py/file

Comment: theres the py file

Comment: let me post the ui file

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/h3kl33irks8b0oe/untitledfirst.ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you must do is connect the clicked signal of the button to some function, but for that you must know the name of the function, for that we go to Object Inspector:

[image]

There we see that the name of the button is `pushButton`. So using the main.py that shows the code is as follows:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile

def foo():
    print("clicked")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    file = QFile("mainwindow.ui")
    if not file.open(QFile.ReadOnly):
        sys.exit(-1)

    loader = QUiLoader()
    window = loader.load(file)
    window.pushButton.clicked.connect(foo)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```